# Selecting the two most widespread colors among turtles and list them

Tags: netlogo

I am stuck on a simple procedure. I have a model with two turtle breeds: citizens and governments. I would like to ask the government to: 1) count and list foreach color, how many citizens have the color? 2) What are the two most common colors? 3) add the colors to a list, 4) look if neighbors have the same two items in the list. I need help for the first 3 points.

I tried with the following reporter

```
to-report frequency [i lst]
  report length filter [? = i] list
end
```

and I tried with this code

```
to top-ideas
  ask governments [
    let x citizens with [idcit = [idgov] of myself]  ;; this are the citizens of controlled by the government
    let xlist [5 15 25 35 45 55 65 85 95 125] ;; this is my list of possible colors
    foreach sort xlist [ ask ? [ 
        let y count x with [color = ?]]]]
  end
```

This code is of incomplete. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed?

Thank you for the help.

Edit: Deleted additional question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting could be done more efficiently by using the table extension, but this will get you started:

```
breed [gvts gvt]
breed [cits cit]

gvts-own [most-common] ;get rid of id
cits-own [my-gvt]  ; use the gvt rather than an id

globals [all-colors]  ;avoid repeated list creation

to setup
  ca
  set all-colors [5 15 25 35 45 55 65 85 95 125]
  create-gvts 2
  create-cits 25 [
    set color one-of all-colors
    set my-gvt one-of gvts
  ]
end

to top-ideas
  ask gvts [
    let _mine cits with [my-gvt = myself]  ;no ids
    let _cts color-counts-desc _mine
    set most-common map first sublist _cts 0 2
  ]
end

to-report color-counts-desc [#agts]  ;most of the answer is HERE
  let _cs [color] of #agts
  let _cts map [list ? (freq ? _cs)] all-colors
  report sort-by [last ?1 >= last ?2] _cts
end

;;this is from the documentation for reduce
;; count the number of occurrences of an item in a list
to-report freq [#x #lst]
  report reduce
    [ifelse-value (?2 = #x) [?1 + 1] [?1]] (fput 0 #lst)
end
```

Comment: This code is perfect. Thank you so much! Without you, I would have been stuck. I will also follow your advice and try to avoid repeated list creation.

Comment: I have an additional problem with procedure number 4 (the one I thought I knew how to do). I have edited my question and added there the procedure that I am trying to run. I am asking to 'governments' to see if any of the two color numbers contained in their 'most-common' list is shared by at least 40% of the population of its neighbors. If so, they have to set their variable 'a-attack?' as true. It seems the problem with my code is in the last line?

Comment: @Misclogo In such circumstances, you should create a new question.  But in any case, that final code block simply creates a local variable and then resets the value -- you are not changing the attribute.

Separately, do you really need to sort your targets?  In seems unlikely that this is a good idea.  If you worried about exact replication, you should use `random-seed` to deal with that.

Comment: I am posting a new question as you suggested. Thank you

Comment: The question is at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337294/ask-a-turtle-to-check-if-30-of-other-turtles-have-colors-equals-to-the-one-it-l). I'm still stuck, unfortunately.